# SQL query required

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables as follows

```
companyid name      
1         pwc       
2         dell      
3         microsoft 
4         google    
5         yahoo     
6         twitter   

companyid  state        month   powerconsumption

1          newyork       jan    240
2          california    jan    130    
3          arizona       jan    210
4          texas         jan    130
5          texas         jan    650
6          california    jan    310
2          arizona       jan    340
```

I want to have a query to list the company in each state which consumed maximum power in the month of jan.So the result in case of above data will be

```
arizona    dell      340
california twitter   310
newyork    pwc       240
texas      yahoo     650
```

Comment: Show your best attempt and tell us what, specifically, you are having trouble with.

Comment: i am learning sql and not getting how to approach this problem.

Comment: It is not duplicate.The data is same ,but the query is different .I don't wanted to mix two questions and so asked a new question

Comment: You have arizona with both 3 and 2 is this a typo?

Comment: It is not a typo.texas and california also has more than one companies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer and that seems the best way for me. It is having a sub query,but i don't see a way to avoid that.

select t2.state,t1.name,t2.powerconsumption 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.companyid =t2.companyid 
 where t2.powerconsumption =(select MAX(t3.powerconsumption) from table2 t3 where t3.state=t2.state and t3.month='jan')

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76d31f/1)**

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT name FROM company WHERE (companyid = (SELECT TOP (1) companyid FROM consumption WHERE (state = a.state) AND (month = a.month) ORDER BY powerconsumption DESC))) AS company,
 state, 
month,
(SELECT TOP (1) powerconsumption FROM consumption AS consumption_1 WHERE (state = a.state) AND (month = a.month) ORDER BY powerconsumption DESC) AS powerconsumption 
FROM dbo.consumption AS a

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT x.State,
    c.Name AS CompanyName,
    x.PowerConsumption
FROM
(
SELECT  pc.CompanyID, pc.State, pc.PowerConsumption,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY pc.State ORDER BY pc.PowerConsumption DESC) AS Rnk
FROM    dbo.PowerConsumptionTable pc
WHERE   pc.Month = 'jan'
) x     INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyTable c ON x.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
WHERE   x.Rnk = 1
```